# Camel recipientList/multicast with aggregation strategy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-camel

```
from("direct:processRequest").multicast(aggregationStrategy).parallelProcessing().
                to("bean:abcService?method=getProductInfo",
                        "bean:xyzService?method=getProductInfo").end().
                to("bean:transformerBean");
```

The  route above works perfectly, but I want to use **dynamic URLs** inside `to(..)`.

---

By consequence I modified my route to the following:

**Route:**

```
from("direct:processRequest").multicast(aggregationStrategy).parallelProcessing().
    bean(RecipientListBean.class).end().
    to("bean:transformerBean");
```

**RecipientListBean.java:**

```
@Component
public class RecipientListBean {
    @RecipientList
    public String[] route(@Header("countryCode") String countryCode) {
        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(countryCode, "IN")) {
            return new String[]{"bean:xyzService?method=getProductInfo",
                    "bean:abcService?method=getProductInfo"};
        } else {
            return new String[]{"bean:xyzService?method=getProductInfo"};
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here It works but the **aggregation is not working**.

Comment: Use toD for dynamic uris

Comment: does `toD` take multiple uri's ? in my case I have to invoke 1 or more bean components@ClausIbsen

Comment: No its a single endpoint.

Comment: Is your routing to recipients working okay? Is it going to those two as expected? Are you getting the parallel processing you expect?

Comment: yes routing and parallel processing is working as expected , but The output is not the aggregated data, it is just the output from last invoked bean  @DariusX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the multicast() interacts with the recipientList(), but the latter already supports the concepts of multicast/aggregation, and parallel processing.

So, something like this should work:

```
from("direct:processRequest")
    .recipientList(header("myHeader"))
    .aggregationStrategy(aggregationStrategy)
    .parallelProcessing()
    .to("bean:transformerBean");
```

Also, if you prefer to use the @RecipientList annotation, that also supports parameters for parallel-processing and aggregationStrategy.

Comment: how to inject dynamic uri's into `header`? @Darius

Comment: Thanks bru. worked . Injecting recipients in the processor -> ``` from("direct:processRequest").process(new RecipientListBean()).recipientList(header("recipients"))
                .aggregationStrategy(aggregationStrategy)
                .parallelProcessing()
                .to("bean:transformerBean");```

Comment: Yup, but I didn't show that because I thought you might prefer to continue using the @RecipientList annotation instead. If so, you can add some parameters to that and can avoid setting headers (same effect, just different way to code).